# Confusion about $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/3) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was reading in my Abstract Algebra book that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/3) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2$. This definition is a bit confusing to me because they never specified what operation we are working under. In general, do there occur times when isomorphisms are stated like this but the operation is not given and if so how can we prove the two are isomorphic if a binary operation is assumed but not explicitly given?

Comment: The binary operation of $\text{aut}(G)$ is function composition by convention.

Comment: The integers are usually (always?) defined as a group via addition, and the automorphism group has composition.

Comment: So if they say $\mathbb{Z}/2$ without giving any binary operation it is implied addition?

Comment: I agree it's frustrating, but you will probably find in the book at least one statement of the form "for the set $G=\cdots$ we shall always assume that the group operation is $\cdots$".  If you don't know what the group operation is, then there is pretty much nothing you can prove about the group, other than things which are true in all groups.

Comment: @David So if we are proving something in general, such as $\text{Inn}(G) \simeq G/Z(G)$, we prove this is true for all groups and as a result all binary operations?

Comment: @T.Bongers You're back!  Raise your group operation Bongers!  $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}, +) ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ (\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}), \circ)$

Comment: @JohnRyan Anything true in all groups must be proved (ultimately) from the group axioms, though usually one will "short cut" the working by using the axioms to prove elementary results, then the elementary results to prove advanced results, then the advanced results to prove OMG-results.

Comment: @JohnRyan exactly. Really, it doesn't matter whether we write an operation as $\circ$, $+$, $\times$, or $\star$. The binary operation is just a function that takes an ordered pair of group elements and spits out a new group element, under very specific constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The operation is not always given because in those instances the operation is fairly "self-evident" as none other makes reallys ense. For example in $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ (as how it should be written), what are we dealing with here? We are dealing with homomorphisms, or more precisely isomorphims $h:\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ so what kind of operations make sense talking about then? We have really only two options, either
$$h\cdot g=h(x)\cdot g(x)$$
or
$$h\cdot g = h\circ g(x)$$
Anything else is pretty much either a derivation or meaningless. The former though provides an issue, namely
$$h\cdot g (x\cdot y) = h(x\cdot y) \cdot g(x\cdot y) = h(x)\cdot h(y)\cdot g(x)\cdot g(y)\neq  h\cdot g(x)\cdot h\cdot g(y)$$
so unless the underlying group is abelian we have that the product is not closed, it generates elements not within $\text{Aut}$ and as such it is meaningless. That leaves us only with the composition product to work with as being meaningful. This is just an example because in many cases we have similar problems arising. In others the unstated operation is just more natural. The one we saw fail here for example is more natural in an abelian group, at which it can be used instead, in dual groups/modules for example this is the case, I should also state here that in the dual the composition is equally meaningless by the nature of the elements of the module.

Through the same reason for example $\mathbb{Z}_n=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ there is only one option there. We have no matter what that $0\in \mathbb{Z}_n$. However $0\in\mathbb{Z}$ and can we find some $a\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $0n=1$? No by nature of integers and multiplication this cannot be found, so as that element exists in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ we cannot have multiplication being the implied operation as we then have 1 element lacking an inverse, which is forbidden in groups as all elements have it. Thus the only operation left is normal addition.